# CakePHP3: group by associated

Tags: cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

Is it possible to group a result set by associated?

I have the following associations

**AgthemesTable**

```
$this->belongsTo('Sites');
$this->hasMany('Agthemelanguages');
```

**AgthemeLanguagesTable**

```
$this->belongsTo('Languages');
```

As I want to get all `Agthemes` for each `Agthemelanguages`, I wrote the following query:

```
$agThemes = $this->Agthemes->find('all')
->select(['id', 'name', 'approved', 'published'])
    ->contain ([
            'Sites' => function ($q) {
                return $q->select(['id'])
                ->autoFields(false);
            },
            'Agthemelanguages.Languages' => function ($q) use ($localized_name) {
                return $q->select(
                        [
                                'id',
                                'code',
                                'code3',
                                $localized_name
                        ]
                        );
            }
        ]
    )
    ->where([
                'approved' => true,
                'published' => true
            ])
    ->matching(
            'Sites', function ($q) use($site_id) {
                return $q->where([
                    'Sites.id' => $site_id
                ]);
        }
    )
    ->group('language_id')
    ->all();
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'language_id' in 'group statement'
```

Effectively, there is no `AgthemeLanguages` in the generated sql query:

```
SELECT Agthemes.id AS `Agthemes__id`, Agthemes.name AS `Agthemes__name`, Agthemes.approved AS `Agthemes__approved`, Agthemes.published AS `Agthemes__published` FROM agthemes Agthemes INNER JOIN sites Sites ON (Sites.id = :c0 AND Sites.id = (Agthemes.site_id)) WHERE (approved = :c1 AND published = :c2) GROUP BY language_id
```

Without `group` statement, I get suc kind of result:

```
'items' => [
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Agtheme) {

        'id' => (int) 40,
        'name' => '...',
        'approved' => (int) 1,
        'published' => (int) 1,
        'agthemelanguages' => [
            (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Agthemelanguage) {

                'id' => (int) 372,
                'agtheme_id' => (int) 40,
                'language_id' => (int) 1,
                'name' => '....',
                'comment' => '....',
                'language' => object(App\Model\Entity\Language) {

                    'id' => (int) 1,
                    ...
                },
                ...,
           ],
           ...,
        },
        ...
    ]
```

How to define such query?
Al

**EDIT**

I finally got what I expect writing the query like that but it needs to make another query first to know all available `Agthemes` and put their ids in a `$agThemeIds` array:

```
$agThemeLanguages = $this->Languages->find('all')
->select(
                        [
                                'id',
                                'code',
                                'code3',
                                $localized_name
                        ]
                        )
    ->contain ([
            'Agthemelanguages' => function ($q) use ($agThemeIds) {
                        return $q->where(['agtheme_id IN ' => $agThemeIds]);
                    }
        ]
    )
    ->matching('Agthemelanguages', function ($q) use ($agThemeIds) {
        return $q->where(['agtheme_id IN ' => $agThemeIds]);
    })
    ->group(['Languages.id'])                           
    ->all();
```

Comment: Why don't you query from the other side, ie via `Agthemelanguages`? Side note: You really need to format your code more readibly... I already feel stressed just by looking at it.

Comment: @ndm, ok thanks, Yes second method is ok for me, I'm just curious if it's possible to group/order on associated in fact..

Comment: From the php side, sure. You could group/order using [Collections](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html).